# Voltage Stabilizer and USB Hub

Tags: usb, power-supply, power, usb-hub, surge-protection

I need to use a voltage stabilizer to secure my USB Hub (Anker PowerPort 6), but the stabilizer is slightly underpowered. It is rated at 1.3A, 300W (230V).

My Anker has input requirements of 1.4A (it's total output is only 60W at 5V per port).

My question is, which of the following will happen?

1. I'll just need to make sure I'm not using more than 1.3A (probably only 1.2A really for safety)... and always need to make sure the device doesn't try to get more from the stabilizer?
2. The USB Hub simply won't work because it checks to see if it can draw 1.4A at startup and will not operate below that?

I'm really hoping it is #1?!

Also, what will happen if the USB Hub DOES try to draw more amps than the stabilizer is rated for?

Asking this after trying to find the info online...

Comment: Most likely outcome is #1. Hubs are usually not clever enough to check for max power available. However I would advise against this setup. It will most likely work as a short-term solution but it can and will let you down one day. Power ratings exist for the reason. Devices supplied with not enough power are not guaranteed to function as intended by manufacturer.

Comment: 1.3 A is likely the input of the stabilizer at 230V. It's output at 5 V must be much higher, otherwise it would be very-very inefficient.

Comment: @MátéJuhász You're right, because 230 V * 1,3 A = 299 W, so it matches OP's info. You should put that in an answer.

Comment: Hm... but the specs online say 1.3A is the capacity, and that it is meant for 32" LCD TV.  So I'm still thinking they are talking about output, not input.  The model (forgot to mention) is "V-Guard Crystal Mini".  The reason I don't just buy a higher amp stabilizer by the way is weight and size. The next one up (at 2 amp) is over 3 kg (this one is 1.5kg). I need to travel with this thing in my suitcase (traveling in India long term... so many power fluctuations, don't get me started on that!).  Thanks to those who have already chimed in.

Comment: Also, I didn't say that the stabilizer outputs at 5V.  The stabilizer obviously also outputs at 230V (I think all stabilizers output a steady voltage normal for that region of the world... in my case, 230V).  The HUB outputs at 5V for each of the six ports.  The hub's total output is 12A, 60W.  Hope this clarifies things.  Hope someone can help me understand.  And thanks again.

Comment: What is "stabilizer" and why you think you need one? The power supply in your hub (I assume it takes mains AC) is the "stabilizer" already, it likely works from 100 AC to 240 AC.  If you mean "battery-powerd backup-UPS", than it might need a different angle to look at.

Comment: I blew multiple adapters over the past few weeks due to power fluctuations here.  The only adapters that got burnt were the adapters with 240V max -- voltage regularly goes above 260V in India :-/  So a voltage stabilizer keeps output current between 200V and 240V.

Comment: Hi, anybody out there?!  Maybe Ganpati is keeping everyone busy!

Answer (score 1):

> but the stabilizer is slightly underpowered. It is rated at 1.3A, 300W (230V)

1.3 A is the input of the stabilizer (1.3 A * 230 V = 299 W).

Having output 1.3 A too would be very-very inefficient. I suppose output current is higher.

Answer (score 0):

Got the correct answer I think (on another forum). Here is the answer:

"you can comfortably use the USB hub with this stabilizer.

Your stabilizer is rated at 300w and your usb hub is max rated at 60w

That 1.4 amp is at 5 volt for the usb hub and 1.3 amp is at 230 volt for the stabilizer."